# What does res mean in this context?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a vue code and there's a variable i see everywhere on it, but i do not know what this variable is or what it's getting.

Here's a function using it

```
        cancelDocument() {
            Alert.YesNo("Tem certeza?", "Você está invalidando este documento e ele será bloqueado permanentemente!").then(res => {
                if(res) {

                    this.loading.cancelingDocument = true
                    model.setLikeCanceled(this.document.id).then(res => {
                        this.document.status = res
                        this.loading.cancelingDocument = false
                    }).catch(err => {
                        this.loading.cancelingDocument = false
                    })

                }
            })
        }
```

i'm new in the field, and i just can't find what this res is. I suppose it tries to get something from the html it's being used on but how?

Comment: Res is not related to Vue itself, it's a variable that contains the Alert.YesNo result.

Comment: `res` is just a variable name that will contain the response, you can name it how you want, also `banana` or whatever. `res` is usually the shortening of `response` or `result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the parameter declared for that callback function:

```
Alert.YesNo("Tem certeza?", "Você está...permanentemente!").then(res => {
// --------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Doesn't have to be called `res`, the name doesn't matter. I'm guessing "res" is for "resposta" (we often also use it in English-centric programming, for "response").

The `YesNo` dialog box fulfills its promise with a flag for the answer. `res` is the flag.

The code within that `then` handler calls another function, `setLikeCanceled`, which *also* returns a promise. The `then` handler on that promise is written to use `res` as the parameter name. This is a **different** parameter than the first one, containing the fulfillment value from `setLikeCanceled`. (Having the same identifier used in two nested scopes like that is called *shadowing*: The inner identifier *shadows* the outer one, making it inaccessible in the inner scope.) Is the *inner* `res`, not the outer one, that gets assigned to `this.document.status`.

Comment: so in this case this.document.status would be receiving the response from the alert?

Comment: @BrunoSouza - No, because there are two **separate** parameters called `res` in that code. I've updated the answer to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

In the function above, the setLikeCanceled method is running asynchronously. The result of the function is being handled via a native Javascript promise (we can tell because .then() and .catch() are reserved for promises).

When it finishes executing, the returned value can then be used in whatever way your code needs BUT you need that value to be set before your function is allowed to proceed. In this case, "res" is just a reference to the result of the promise. I can't tell you exactly what it stands for but could be either resolution or response. It doesn't really matter as you could change that to whatever you want. It's not a reserved word in Javascript.

Promises are very common in AJAX calls where there's some lag time before a value is set because of a web service call or because you need to reach out to a database.